# Odd occurrence in using app.use(parseExpressRawBody())

Tags: javascript, json, express, parse-platform

Maybe this is simple, maybe this is a bug on Parse - would like to know if anyone has had the same problem and a possible solution.

What I'm trying to do:

- I'm sending a JSON request from an app called FormEntry to my Parse app
- The body comes in like this: json={"someLabel" : "someValue"}
- I would like to take the entire body and create a Parse.Cloud.httpRequest over to Zapier to perform some functions.

Now, the problem seems to be this:

On random occasions (i.e. I have no idea why), the body is sent (as shown by the logs) where there is a trailing comma at the end of the last pair in the JSON object. e.g. like this json={"lastLabel" : "lastValue",}
The number of elements in 'normal' and 'incorrect' objects seem to be the same, so it's simply just another comma added. And I have no idea why.

My setup:

- Using *app.use(parseExpressRawBody());* only and not the standard *app.use(express.bodyParser());*  which doesn't provide access to the raw body.
- Because parseExpressRawBody converts the body to a buffer I need to turn it back into a string to send it in the HTTP request in a meaningful way. Therefore I use: var body = req.body.toString();
- When logging this var to the Parse console it looks to be format back from the buffer fine.

And that's about it. Nothing complex going on here but a real annoying bug that I just haven't found a sensible way of understanding. Would SUPER appreciate anyone who has seen this before or who could point me in a direction to focus on.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that "app called FormEntry"? If it does really sends malformed JSON, then that's not your fault.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Bergi The app is actually called FormEntry, google it and you'll see. I guess I had the assumption that it was sending consistent JSON but I'll bring it up with them too and see if they are aware of anything. I thought it might have been something to do with the parseExpressRawBody

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on this. Not a solution that answers why there is malformed JSON but a hack to get the right result.

The purpose of the HTTP request was to point over to Zapier so I wrote a Zapier script that would deal with the malformed JSON. Added here for anyone else who needs it.

```
"use strict";
var Zap = { newSubmission_catch_hook: function(bundle) {
      var body = bundle.request.content;
      var cleanTop = body.substring(5,body.length);
      var cleanChar = cleanTop.length;  
      var condition = cleanTop.substring(cleanChar-2,cleanChar);
      function testCase(condition,cleanTop) {
        if (condition != ",}"){
            console.log("Everything is fine, returning JSON");
          return cleanTop;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Nope! We have an error, cleaning end");
         var cleanEnd = cleanTop.substr(0,cleanChar-2) + '}';
            console.log("The object now ends with: " + cleanEnd.substr(-10));
           return cleanEnd;
        }
      }
    var newBody = JSON.parse(testCase(condition,cleanTop));

    return newBody;
    }
};
```